# Why is (new RegExp("\\w") === /\w/) false in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried the following in Chrome’s console:

```
var r1 = new RegExp("\\w"); // → /\w/
var r2 = /\w/; // → /\w/
r1 === r2; // → false
r1 == r2; // → false
r1.toString() === r2.toString(); // → true
r1.source === r2.source; // → true
```

I don't understand why it does that.

Comment: related, the actual difference between them other than location in memory is `r1 = new RegExp("\\w");` gets compiled at runtime, `r2 = /\w/;` is compiled when the script is evaluated.

Comment: When comparing two objects, `==` and `===` compare to see if the objects are actually the same actual object reference.  They don't look at the contents of the object.  They just check to see if they are physically the same object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are two different `RegExp` instances, so by directly comparing them with `==` or `===` you're comparing two unequal references, resulting in `false`.

But when you compare either their `toString()` serializations or their sources, you're comparing their string representations by value. Since they're basically the exact same pattern and flags, comparing their string representations will return `true`.

Comment: +1 Even `/\w/ === /\w/` yields `false`; the reason does not lie in `new Regexp` vs a literal.

Comment: Those are two different *objects*, different instances of the `RegExp` class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote from the [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) documentation on MDN:

> Note that an object is converted into a primitive if, and only if, its
>   comparand is a primitive. **If both operands are objects, they're
>   compared as objects, and the equality test is true only if both refer
>   the same object.**

`new RegExp("\\w")` is an object and so is `/\w/`. Both instantiated separately. Need I say more?